# How do I get notification from a `CEdit` box?

Tags: windows, mfc, desktop-application

I have a `CEdit` box where a user can enter relevant information. As soon as he\she starts writing in the box, I need a notification so that I can call `doSomething()` to perform some other task. Does Windows provide a callback, and if so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 14):

With MFC there's no callback as such, rather you do this by implementing a handler for the appropriate event. You need to handle one of two events: `WM_CHAR` or `EN_CHANGE`

Handle the dialog's `EN_CHANGE` for example duplicating in realtime the entered text elsewhere on the dialog. You need to firstly add an entry in the dialog's message map, and secondly override the appropriate handler:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CstackmfcDlg, CDialog)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDIT1, &CstackmfcDlg::OnEnChangeEdit1)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CstackmfcDlg::OnEnChangeEdit1()
    {
    CString text;
    m_edit.GetWindowText(text);
    m_label.SetWindowText(text); // update a label control to match typed text
    }
```

Or, handle the editbox class's `WM_CHAR` for example preventing input of certain characters, e.g. ignore anything other than a digit for numerical entry. Derive a class from CEdit, handle the `WM_CHAR` event of that class (not the dialog) and make your edit control an instance of that class.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CCtrlEdit, CEdit)
    ON_WM_CHAR()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CCtrlEdit::OnChar(UINT nChar, UINT nRepCnt, UINT nFlags)
    {
    // Do nothing if not numeric chars entered, otherwise pass to base CEdit class
    if ((nChar >= '0' && nChar <= '9') || VK_BACK == nChar)
        CEdit::OnChar(nChar, nRepCnt, nFlags);
    }
```

Note that you can use the VS IDE to put in stubs for the handler overrides by using the Properties bar with the mouse selection in the message map block.

**EDIT:** Added example code, and corrected explanation of `WM_CHAR` which I had wrong.

Comment: WM_CHAR isn't sufficient since you can paste into the control for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you double click on the edit box in the resource editor it automatically creates the OnEnChanged event for you.

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that you have an MFC dialog application.

The class wizard can be started with a right-click:
[image: Start class wizard]

Double-click the Control ID (has an icon with a small green plus) of the new edit control to add the corresponding member variable to the class.

[image: New proposed variable created]

The class and event wizards will update the class definition and add a `CEdit` member:

```cpp
afx_msg void OnEnChangeEdit1(); // Added by event wizard
CEdit m_edit1; // member added by class wizard
```

The class wizard will update the function:

```cpp
void CMFCApplication5Dlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_EDIT1, m_edit1); // new variable added with class wizard
}
```

Double-clicking the control or right-clicking and selecting the add event wizard will update the message map and create the function declaration and definition:

```cpp
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplication5Dlg, CDialogEx)
    ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDIT1, &CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnEnChangeEdit1) // new event handler added with wizard
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Finally the code may be updated to interact with the edit control:

```cpp
void CMFCApplication5Dlg::OnEnChangeEdit1()
{
    // TODO:  Add your control notification handler code here
    CString text;
    m_edit1.GetWindowText(text);
    //m_edit1.SetWindowText(text);
}
```