# MFC edit box modify even

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, editbox, onkillfocus

I want event on modifying MFCedit box, i.e. when I try to write or delete any letter.

I am getting the event on killing the focus but that's not required.

I want event while modifying the content of edit box.

Comment: This is fairly basic stuff. Have you Googled for a tutorial about the `CEdit` class? There are events for handling the `EN_CHANGE` and these are exposed in the IDE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get notification from a \`CEdit\` box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062217/how-do-i-get-notification-from-a-cedit-box)

Comment: @acraigh5075 Good catch. I forgot about double clicking the control. Useful when you want this event handler (as it is the default handler).

Answer (score 2):

To add to the existing answer(s), this can be done by adding the `EN_CHANGE` event handler for the control. This is a straightforward task using the IDE in Visual Studio.

There are a few approaches to this.

---

### Method 1: Right-click the EDIT control and add an event handler:

[image: Context Menu]

Click **Add Event Handler...** on  the context menu and then locate the handler to add it:

[image: Add Handler]

Make sure your dialog class is selected and that the `EN_CHANGE` message type is selected and then click OK to add the boiler plate code to your class. Now you can do what you need to do.

---

### Method 2: Using the Properties Panel

[image: Properties Panel]

Make sure that the control is selected and that the Properties Panel is visible on screen.

1. Click the **Control Events** (lightning icon) and you will see a list of events for the EDIT control.
2. Locate `EN_CHANGE` and click the drop-down arrow.

You'll see a item to select there which will add the event handler for you.

---

### Method 3: Using Class Wizard

Right-click the **DIALOG** resource (*not* the EDIT control) and select **Class Wizard...**

[image: Context Menu]

Then you can add the control using the Class Wizard:

[image: Class Wizard]

To do this:

1. Select the EDIT control ID on the list on the left.
2. Select the `EN_CHANGE` event handler.
3. Click the **Add Handler...** button.

As you can see, there are several ways to add the `EN_CHANGE` event handler.

Comment: This doesn't explain **what** to do, just **how** to do it. Using an IDE whose MFC support is flaky at best. There hasn't been a Class Wizard in Visual Studio 2002, 2003, 2005, and 2008, i.e. for close to a decade. Likewise, the resource editor has been broken for *years* now on multi-monitor systems with different DPI settings for different displays.

Comment: Disagree. All my screen shots are from VC2019. There is a Class Wizard!!!!!!

Comment: And your other comments are unrelated to the issue at hand. And as I stated at the start of my answer, it was IN ADDITION to exist. Thank you.

Comment: I listed the Visual Studio versions that didn't ship with an MFC Class Wizard. 2019 is not on that list. 2019 is on the list of versions with a completely broken, unusable dialog editor, though. The list of Visual Studio versions with working MFC support is this: Everything up to and including Visual C++ 6.0, VS 2010, 2012, and 2015. That's all.

Comment: I have no desire to argue my friend. Sorry if I miss understood you.

Answer (score 1):

Changes to the contents of an edit control are reported to clients through an [`EN_CHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change) notification. The `CEdit` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class#remarks) explains how to wire up class members to notification callbacks. In this case you'll want to add an `ON_EN_CHANGE` entry to your message map.